# Best Practice for State Management in a Distributed ASP.NET MVC 4 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

I am building an enterprise application with ASP.NET MVC 4, following N-tier architecture (including web farm with load balancing and possibly application farm). What is the best practice to manage state for such a distributed architecture?

I know I can go for SQL state management, but will it be a good choice keeping the performance in mind (especially considering many inter-server calls)? What other options I have if I do not want to use `Session` variables at all (due to performance issues or I don't want to handle session timeouts)? How about using `@Html.Serialize()`?

Apologies if similar question has been asked before, but my search did not result in any definitive answer.

**EDIT:** Here are some of the key metrics: 
Volume of users - 1.2 millions
Concurrency - During peak time, the transactions are as high as 800 per minute
Geographic diversity - US and Europe
Caching - there is plan to use distributed caching (AppFabric)
Availability - 99.99%. 
This is an internet site for one of largest retailers in the world and we expect a very high growth rate.

Comment: What volume of users, transactions, peak periods, page size, server capacity, distributed transactions, geographic diversity, caching, backup, availability, disaster recovery, concurrent users, growth rates, etc. do you expect? I guess you'll need to add a whole lot more detail to get specialized help. Without these metrics / non-functional requirements you are likely to get rather general answers.

Comment: @Kane, please refer to the EDIT for some of the key metrics.

Comment: I guess the easiest would be to build a Single-Page-Application and handle as much from session state as possible directly in the browser in JS

Comment: @zahorak, do you have a link with example of how to handle session state in client-side with SPA?

Comment: You have cookies and Local Storage and can use frameworks like AngularJS or KnockoutJS. Than you can minimize the number of cases, where you'd need a session state. In the best case, you'd reduce it to 0, since the client (browser) wouldn't be stateless any more.

Comment: @zahorak, Thanks. Are you referring to something like this? http://craigcav.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/simple-client-storage-for-view-models-with-amplifyjs-and-knockout/

Comment: @fuzzygeek yes, here you have the W3C api documentation (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) also very easy to use. I used for instance session storage to remember filters for different grids and local storage to remember configurations like paging and sort columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. This certainly looks like a good solution.